# How to pass a value in a variable

Tags: linux, shell, variables, unix

I want to pass a value `${name}` which is coming from other environments
to below update flag.

```
$updateflag='${name}.tsting.com'             

$echo ${name}        $TEST        $echo "${updateflag}"     >>>>> I am
getting below              $updateflag='${name}.tsting.com'
```

while I am looking for something like :

```
updateflag='TEST.tsting.com'
```

Can anyone advise? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need double quotes and less prefixing with `$`. Does something like this help?

```
updateflag="${name}.tsting.com"
echo "${updateflag}"
```

Comment: Thanks for response  , I already tried to double quotes it but it failed .

Comment: Please revise your question. It doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for `eval`

```
name=TEST
updateflag='${name}.foo'
eval declare "expanded=\"$updateflag\""
echo "$expanded"
```

```
TEST.foo
```